# Problem with fixed navigation after page reload

Tags: javascript, css, position, fixed

In my example a navigation - embedded in the header - should be fixed at the top of the browser window if the document was scrolled down by a certain amount.

The equivalent script works so far, but shows the following problem in firefox and chrome (but not in edge and IE11):

If the document is scrolled down and the navigation is fixed - and then the reload button of the browser or the F5 key are pressed or when i am leaving the page and then return, the navigation remains fixed.

I've tried to remove the ".fixed"-class at every load event, but of course it does not take effect because of there is no real reload.

I think that behavior can only be reproduced in a separate document?!

Does anyone have a hint on how I can solve the problem?

```js
var header, nav, navtop, verticalpos;

function fixed_nav() {

  "use strict";

  verticalpos = window.pageYOffset;

  if (verticalpos >= navtop) {

    nav.setAttribute('class', 'fixed');

  } else {

    nav.removeAttribute('class');

  }

}

function init() {

  "use strict";

  header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];

  nav = header.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];

  navtop = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixed_nav, false);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

nav {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  display: block;
  /* IE 11 */
}

div {
  max-width: 25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

header>div {
  height: 10rem;
}

nav>div {
  height: 100%;
}

main>div {
  padding: 2rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
}

section {
  padding: 0rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
}

h2,
p:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: auto auto 2rem auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* translateZ-hack */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Fixed</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <div></div>

    <nav>

      <div></div>

    </nav>

  </header>

  <main>

    <div>

      <section>

        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

      </section>

    </div>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in chrome, you should add call to fixed_nav function inside your init function.
This will fix the back issue.

Comment: Sorry, does not solve the problem. Still the same behaviour in FF and Chrome / Window 10 - even if the function fixed_nav is triggered within the function init ...

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by adding the two additional events pageshow and pagehide, to ensure a reset of the (fixed) navigation even if the document comes from the cache after using the reset button, forward- / backward-button or the f5-key.

```js
var html, header, nav, navtop, verticalpos;

function fixed_nav() {

  "use strict";

  verticalpos = window.pageYOffset;

  if (verticalpos >= navtop) {

    nav.setAttribute('class', 'fixed');

  } else {

    nav.removeAttribute('class');

  }

}

function init() {

  "use strict";

  html = document.documentElement;

  header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];

  nav = header.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];

  navtop = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

window.addEventListener('pageshow', function() {
  html.scrollTop = 0;
  
  navtop = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  
}, false);

window.addEventListener('pagehide', function() {
  html.scrollTop = 0;
  
  nav.removeAttribute('class');
}, false);

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixed_nav, false);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

nav {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  display: block;
  /* IE 11 */
}

div {
  max-width: 25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

header>div {
  height: 10rem;
}

nav>div {
  height: 100%;
}

main>div {
  padding: 2rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
}

section {
  padding: 0rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
}

h2,
p:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: auto auto 2rem auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* translateZ-hack */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Fixed</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <div></div>

    <nav>

      <div></div>

    </nav>

  </header>

  <main>

    <div>

      <section>

        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>

      </section>

    </div>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Include it in your html file

2)Fix the position of nav. 
3)use media queries.

Comment: My problem does - not - appear in the IE versions Edge and IE11 and i no longer consider versions < IE11. The problem appears in Firefox, Chrome (and others not tested) under the conditions mentioned.